# Animation visible in 3D viewport but not in render mode

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I'm trying to simulate a firework. It works correctly in 3D viewport (I can see the bullet going up and emitting particles) but ansolutely nothing is visible in render mode (except the two objects used for the particles system at the right hand corner of the image).

My file is there :[image]

Can anyone explain me why nothing is rendered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to output properties and turn off "Sequencer":

[image]